# Shopify.dev Cookie Compliance Banner not showing

Tags: cookies, shopify

I am using the Shopify Cookie Compliance Banner (https://shopify.dev/themes/trust-security/cookie-banner) and have followed the setup exactly to display a Cookie Consent Bar on my store.

I've created the cookie-banner.liquid snippet in the snippets directory and have added the following code inside the body tags of the theme.liquid file as instructed:

`{% render 'cookie-banner' %}`

Unfortunately, it's not showing up in my store. When removing the fist line of code from cookie-banner.liquid snippet: `(#cookies-banner { display: none; ... })` it does display, but doesn't remember the users preference and pops back up every time the page is refreshed or re-visited.

Any idea of why this might be happening? I am located in Australia if that makes any difference.

Comment: What is the position of code in your theme?

Comment: Add a `console.log("showBanner is called")` before line 51 on the [code](https://shopify.dev/themes/trust-security/cookie-banner#create-a-snippet-to-host-the-banner) provided by Shopify to see if the function is indeed called. The snippet works as follows: the CSS hides with `display: none` the banner as default, whereas the JS function `showBanner()` overrides the CSS.

Comment: Thanks @UmbertoFontanazza - just to clarify, this is what you mean? 
`if(!userCanBeTracked && userTrackingConsent === 'no_interaction') {
      console.log("showBanner is called")
      showBanner();
    }`

Comment: Yes exactly, load the page of interest and check with the Chrome dev tools in the console tab if the log output is present